# Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 and com.fasterxml.jackson dependecy

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

While porting to `Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1` I noticed that it uses managed version `2.9.2` for `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` and `2.9.0` for `jackson-annotations`.

Why do you use `2.9.0` for `jackson-annotations` and not `2.9.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with their jackson-annotations documentation:

> Annotations module will never contain changes in patch versions,
>    only .0 releases can have changes. We may still release patch versions, but
>    they will be identical to .0 versions, and only released for convenience
>    (developers can line up all Jackson components with same patch version number).

It can be found in: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/master/release-notes/VERSION